# How to print the corresponding parent commit hash when using git log -m --patch

Tags: git-log

When using git log

```
git log -m --patch
```

for a merge commit, it would produce a diff for each parent commit and specify the corresponding parent commit hash, like:

```
commit c82270ac7d31f1c32b0b0d541c4c0b00fe85b4ab (from dd039905f7e2e1f74cddbb67cd0f699c443722e4)
```

But it is not convenient for parsing.

When I use %P in pretty format, it would give me the two parents commit hashes at the same time, like

```
dd039905f7e2e1f74cddbb67cd0f699c443722e4 fdc14f48ff64d9ad8837dafb22c366bc2f
```

and I cannot distinguish which one is the patch for. How can I get the corresponding parent commit hash when using pretty format?

Thanks